# If I want to upper version for a CRAN exist R package (from 0.2.0 to 0.2.1) , do I need to delete "CRAN-RELEASE" in R package?

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran

I find that there is a `CRAN-RELEASE` file inside package after I first time release the package.

It said "This package was submitted to CRAN on 2020-07-25.
Once it is accepted, delete this file and tag the release (commit ...)."

Since I already has version 0.2.0 for the package on CRAN, but do need to release up-version later (e.g. 0.2.1) on CRAN, do I need to keep that `CRAN-RELEASE` file or should I delete it? Will it affect anything?

Also, what is the second half sentence means "tag the release (commit ...)". Is that means I need to do something such as

[image]

Comment: That message was put there by `devtools::release`.  The message is about adding a `git` tag.  The message says you should have deleted the file, so I'd do that before attempting another submission.

Comment: Thank you for helping! So, I just delete that file by hand is that ok? I saw some others said use ```use_github_release()``` to delete. While, that seems like during the process to release the new version

Comment: I think you are getting yourself confused between _making a package release for CRAN_ and _tagging a release at GitHub_.  Two different things.

Comment: @ScarlettZhao:  Sorry, I don't use `devtools`.  Personally, I think it tries too hard to be helpful, but it leads to confusion like yours:  it's a noble failure.  But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also wondered about the phrase "tag the release", but then I found [section 20.7](https://r-pkgs.org/release.html#post-release) of Wickham and Bryan's R-packages book, and it became clear.

For reference: there it says this (let's let a 'couple' mean 'three' ;-) )

> Once your package has been accepted by CRAN, you have a couple of technical tasks to do:
>
> - If you use GitHub, go to the repository release page. Create a new release with tag version v1.2.3 (i.e. “v” followed by the version of your package). Copy and paste the contents of the relevant NEWS.md section into the release notes.
> - If you use git, but not GitHub, tag the release with git tag -a v1.2.3.
> - Add the .9000 suffix to the Version field in the DESCRIPTION to indicate that this is a development version. Create a new heading in NEWS.md and commit the changes.

Comment: you should add relevant parts of the documentation into your answer so if the link becomes invalid your answer will still be useful, see [Your answer is in an other castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/346685)